# Inserting date in the next row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a time-and-motion file in GoogleSheet and I would like to insert a date in the next available cell in a specific column. May I know how do I go about that using Google Script editor?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details about the structure of your spreadsheet and about the date that you want to insert (what is the source of the date?, will you type it directly in the editor?) By the way what do you already know about handling dates in Google Sheets and in the Google Apps Script editor?

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: @David what's wrong with you? You asked help, you got the help. And you don't even care to get any reaction.

Comment: Donwnvote and vote to close since there is no feedback.

Comment: @YuriKhristich I'm sorry for not being able to reply back, we had some terrible things happening in the office and barely got the chance to open my personal laptop.  I will be trying these steps on my next lean time which may not be until this weekend. I'm thankful for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it can be done this way:

```
function insert_date() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A1');
  cell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

This script inserts current date into cell 'A1'.

But in's not quite clear what you're trying to gain.

Here is the code to insert current date into **a first empty cell** in column A:

```
function insert_date_in_first_empty_cell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = sheet.getRange('A1:A');
  var index = col.getValues().flat().findIndex(x => x=='') + 1;
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A' + index);
  cell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

If you want to fill the first empty cell after the last non-empty cell you can change two lines this way:

```
var col = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getDisplayValues().flat();
var index = col.length - col.slice().reverse().findIndex(x => x!='') + 1;
```

[image]

Comment: But the first empty cell may not occur at the bottom of the column

Comment: Of course. But I don't know what exactly @David wants.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, sorry I'm quite a noob in this.  So here's what I would like to gain:  For example I have column A where A1 to A5 is already filled with data. Now, I wish to add a button that will trigger adding date in A6.  Then, pressing the same button will insert date in A7, and so on.  I hope I was saying it clearly, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: My function `insert_date_in_first_empty_cell()` does exactly this. Do you know how to make a button to run a function?

Comment: Here is the sheet with the button. You can make a copy and see how it works https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dP_DUNqSJj5rxVWeRFGa6CemO8zjU4Pqr7-QVaR1PDs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you @Cooper sorry for being inactive here, this was suppose to be my side project but my regular 9-5 got in the way. Again, thankful for your help. Thanks also, yuri.

Comment: @YuriKhristich thanks a lot especially with the sample sheet you provided. I was able to make the Time and Motion template that I need with only 1 button to insert the Date/Time and I used the script that you provided.  you've been really helpful

Comment: PS:    I managed to add cell.setNumberFormat ("hh:mm:ss"); in the end to change the format of the value the button in creating. Again, thanks so much!